# Problems with purchasing in azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I have a problem making the purchase of visual studio monthly subscription, I have the permissions to do this, but the company recently re-signed a domain change and after that I can't make any purchase what steps should I take to fix this. What would I have to do to fix this problem, in the subscription we had to do this it tells me that I don't have the permissions to make the purchase, and in the subscription that I created it lets me enter the number of licenses that I want to buy but when I have to confirm the purchase it doesn't let me, so what do I need to change in Azure from the previous domain to the current one to be able to make the purchases?

I changed my permissions to see if that was it, the person who recognizes him as the owner also wanted to make the purchase but just like I didn't let him, he says he doesn't have permissions. I created another Azure subscription to buy but it still won't let me

Comment: You should contact Microsoft support for support issues like this.

Answer (score -1):

According to your description, you are having issue purchasing VS subscription. VS subscription cannot be purchased in [Azure DevOps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/what-is-azure-devops?view=azure-devops). In Azure DevOps, there is only an access level type "[Visual Studio Subscriber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=set%20of%20features.-,Visual%20Studio%20Subscriber,-%3A%20Assign%20to%20users)". If a user added to the organization has purchased a VS subscription, the system will automatically recognize the user's subscription and set his access level as Visual Studio Subscriber.

As mentioned by Daniel, you could contact Visual Studio Subscription Support. See support [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/subscriptions/support/#talktous).